# EXSLT : date:format-date : parsing date, not parsing time

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, exslt

**Setup :** Apache Xalan 2.7.1

**Input :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<r>
   <generated_date>2015-07-03 11:48</generated_date>
</r>
```

**XSLT :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:xdt="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
            exclude-result-prefixes="xdt">
            <xsl:variable name="generated-date" select="xdt:format-date(//generated_date,'YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')"        />

      <xsl:template match="/">
             <xsl:value-of select="$generated-date"/>
      </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output :**

```
<generated_date>2015-07-03 12:00:00</generated_date>
```

> **Q :** Why I can't figure out why time is not being parsed all along with the date. Time should be equal 11:48:00.

---

> **Note:** Only xslt 1.0 solutions can apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't figure out why time is not being parsed all along with the
>   date.

AFAICT, the reason why it doesn't work for you is that the supplied date/time string is not in one of defined formats that the function accepts - see: http://exslt.org/date/functions/format-date/index.html

If you want to format both date and time, the supplied string must be formatted as `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss` - that is, using `T` as the separator between date and time and including the seconds in the time portion. See it working<sup>1</sup> here: http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKwS

> Only xslt 1.0 solutions can apply.

I am not sure what kind of a solution you're looking for here. The supplied string is already in the required format, except for the missing seconds part, so you could simply output:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(given-date,':00')"/>
```

without requiring any extensions.

---

(1) Note that none of the major XSLT 1.0 processors supports the EXSLT `format-date()` function - and this includes Xalan 2.7.1. Although it seems to be working, officially the function is not available - see:   http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKwS/1

Comment: Apache Xalan 2.7.1 supports format-date function, though maybe not in official release notes - https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/apidocs/org/apache/xalan/lib/ExsltDatetime.html

just wanted to share this